# VS Breaking once list goes past 2(1) rather than cycling back to 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Trying to cycle through my characters but instead it breaks once I click next at the last character. The response given by visual studio is : ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled and referring to my "playerCharacter pc = player[currentPlayerIndex];"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RPGExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private List<PlayerCharacter> player;

        int currentPlayerIndex = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // set up an empty list
            player = new List<PlayerCharacter>();


            // add a couple of players
            player.Add(new PlayerCharacter("Attila"));

            player.Add(new PlayerCharacter("Boromir"));

            // create some weapons (could be in a list too)
            Weapon sword = new Weapon("Broadsword",40,5);

            Weapon leatherShield = new Weapon("Leather Shield",2,35);

            Weapon woodenStaff = new Weapon("Wooden Staff",30,10);

            // and some food
            Food bread = new Food("Bread", 15);

            // because Weapons and food inherit from CollectableObject
            // a player can carry either (polymorphism)

            // equip the players
            player[0].Add(sword);
            player[0].Add(leatherShield);

            player[1].Add(woodenStaff);

            player[1].Add(bread);


            //  display the player we are viewing
            DisplayPlayer(currentPlayerIndex);

        }


        // display info about a player by calling objects to string function
        public void DisplayPlayer(int playerIndex)
        {
            // we number from 1 for the user
            // try removing the brackets around playerIndex + 1 !!!
            lblPlayerInfo.Text = "Player " + (playerIndex + 1);

            PlayerCharacter pc = player[currentPlayerIndex];
            txtPlayers.Text = pc.ToString();
        }

        private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentPlayerIndex > 0)
            {
                currentPlayerIndex--;
                DisplayPlayer(currentPlayerIndex);
            }
        }

        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentPlayerIndex < player.Count)
            {
                currentPlayerIndex++;
                DisplayPlayer(currentPlayerIndex);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `if (currentPlayerIndex < player.Count)` returns true with 0 or 1. But then you increment `currentPlayerIndex++;` making them 1 and 2. Out of range.

Answer (score 0):

You should just DisplayPlayer before incremeent/decrement currentPlayerIndex, or replace strict comparison (<) by comparison with equality (<=)  :)

```
    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentPlayerIndex >= 0)
        {
            currentPlayerIndex--;
            DisplayPlayer(currentPlayerIndex);
        }
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentPlayerIndex < player.Count)
        {
            currentPlayerIndex++;
            DisplayPlayer(currentPlayerIndex);
        }
    }
```